# Xamarin Forms using CrossInAppBilling, How to check if subscription is valid?

Tags: xamarin.forms, in-app-subscription

Documentation: https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/

I'm trying to verify a valid subscription exists for a user, if it does, log them in.

The following will grab all subscription purchases:

```
 var _subscriptionList = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.GetPurchasesAsync(ItemType.Subscription);
```

and I check to see if a user should be allowed to login depending on if a subscription is found.

```
            if (_subscriptionList.Any())
            {
                Login();
            }
```

However I feel this allows users with pending payments, to login(Or anyone that has any kind of subscription record with a state of paid, pending or rejected). So what I have done is put a check in place to observe the "PurchaseState":

```
if (_subscriptionList.Any())
            {
                foreach (var _subscription in _subscriptionList)
                {
                    if (_subscription.State == PurchaseState.Purchased)
                    {
                        Login();
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
```

Is this the correct way to implement? I have tested on Android but the test purchase stays in a state of PurchaseState.Pending, so I had to include "_subscription.State == PurchaseState.PaymentPending" in order to login. I need someone who has experience with this plugin and it's behavior in real time.

Comment: For anyone looking at this in need of an answer, the above code is in fact how you would implement it. Play Store and App Store will both keep the Purchase state in pending, real world behavior is different. It will be either "Purchased" or "Denied".

Comment: hello you get any solution?